# Disabling mouse scrolling in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Everything I've found on the internet has told me that emacs disables mouse scrolling by default, but mine is very enthusiastic and scrolls to its hearts content when my thumbs get too close to the trackpad on my laptop. I have **not** given it permission to do so, and here is my .emacs to prove it:

```
;; Line by line scrolling                                                                                                                                      
(setq scroll-step 1)

;; Turn off backup file creation                                                                                                                               
;;(setq make-backup-files nil)                                                                                                                                 

;; Enable backup files                                                                                                                                         
(setq make-backup-files t)

;; Save all backup files to this directory                                                                                                                     
(setq backup-directory-alist (quote ((".*" . "~/.emacs_backups/"))))

;; Show column number                                                                                                                                          
(column-number-mode 1)

;; Fix C indenting                                                                                                                                             
(setq c-default-style "bsd"
      c-basic-offset 8)
```

Every once and a while my thumbs will brush the track pad, and suddenly I'll be typing in the middle of another line way up or way below from where I had just been. How can I stop this from happening?

**EDIT**
Running M-x customize-option mouse-wheel-mode yields:

Mouse Wheel Mode: [Hide Value] [Toggle]  off (nil)

[State]: CHANGED outside Customize; operating on it here may be unreliable.

Non-nil if Mouse-Wheel mode is enabled. [Hide Rest]
See the command `mouse-wheel-mode' for a description of this minor mode.

Setting this variable directly does not take effect;

either customize it (see the info node`Easy Customization')
or call the function `mouse-wheel-mode'.
Groups: [Mouse]

Comment: What operating system do you use? Do you use Emacs inside a terminal?

Comment: Linux Mint, I alias "emacs" as "emacs -nw".

Comment: Then are you sure that Emacs is scrolling and not your terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's enabled by default (at least since Emacs 23).

To turn it off (locally):

```
(mouse-wheel-mode -1)
```

To turn it off (globally):

```
M-x customize-option mouse-wheel-mode ; set to nil and save
```

But maybe you just want to adjust the settings: Take a look at M-x customize-group mouse RET

Comment: Surprisingly (mouse-wheel-mode -1) didn't fix the problem.
...and I'm not sure what your second suggestion means. :(

Comment: Well this disables `mouse-wheel-mode` locally. To disable it globally you have to customize `mouse-wheel-mode` in the mouse group. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: `mouse-wheel-mode` is a global mode, so the first one should be sufficient.

Comment: Hey guys, check the edit. As looks like as far as emacs is concerned, scrolling is disabled. But it isn't.

Comment: It disables the mouse wheel, but it also constantly makes error ding whenever the mousewheel is touched.

Answer (score 4):

I did the following:

```
;; Disable mouse wheel (and two finger swipe) scrolling because
;; it scrolls horribly and I would rather work without it.

(mouse-wheel-mode -1)

(global-set-key [wheel-up] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [wheel-down] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [double-wheel-up] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [double-wheel-down] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [triple-wheel-up] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [triple-wheel-down] 'ignore)
```

The last part disables the scroll wheel events, which gets rid of the annoying beeping.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to disable all mouse scrolling (including horizontal):

```
(mouse-wheel-mode -1)
(global-set-key [wheel-up] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [double-wheel-up] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [triple-wheel-up] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [wheel-down] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [double-wheel-down] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [triple-wheel-down] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [wheel-left] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [double-wheel-left] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [triple-wheel-left] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [wheel-right] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [double-wheel-right] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [triple-wheel-right] 'ignore)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're seeing is mouse wheel scrolling as much as tap-to-click on your trackpad.  If your mouse pointer is pointed to a different part of the document than where you typing and you accidentally brush the trackpad and your trackpad/OS interprets that as a mouse click, then the your input point will jump to the place the mouse cursor is pointed at.

You can address by disabling tap-to-click or by using the feature availabe with some trackpad/OSes that disable the trackpad all together while you're typing.  How you do those will depend on your trackpad/driver/OS combination.

Comment: No, I run Linux Mint on a MacBook Pro, and the track pad requires a heavy click in order to register a mouse button push.