# How do I mouse scroll in Emacs in the terminal? I haven't gotten mouse-wheel-mode to work

Tags: emacs

I use Emacs in the terminal, either 23 or 24 depending on which machine I'm SSHed into, which are all Ubuntu / Mint. I also have the line `alias emacs='emacsclient -a "" -t'` in my .bashrc file, if that matters. I've wanted to figure out how to be able to scroll with my mouse for months, but I can't seem to, even if I'm using Emacs locally.

Every time I open Emacs in a terminal, I have a scroll bar on the right, but it is not functional, because the part that you normally drag (that part that moves when you scroll) fills the entire height of the scroll bar, and is immovable.

I've seen many people suggest `M-x mouse-wheel-mode`. When I begin to type it out, tab complete shows me the list of completions, and this isn't on it. The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378582/disabling-mouse-scrolling-in-emacs) states it's included and on by default. If that's true, something else is wrong. Before finding this, I've also tried finding a `.el` for it, and haven't succeeded in that either.

I've gotten `(xterm-mouse-mode)` working. Which may only be related in that it's proof to Emacs that I have a mouse.

I don't know what to try next. Any ideas?

Comment: `mouse-wheel-mode` is defined in `mwheel.el`. It does not seem to be included in emacs 23 but only emacs 24. On emacs 24, on my machine, just using `(xterm-mouse-mode)` works. What is your `TERM` environment variable before you launch emacs?

Answer (score 9):

Adding the following let's me scroll in terminal emacs:

```
;;;; Mouse scrolling in terminal emacs
(unless (display-graphic-p)
  ;; activate mouse-based scrolling
  (xterm-mouse-mode 1)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-4>") 'scroll-down-line)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-5>") 'scroll-up-line)
  )
```

Comment: That did it for me. It's slow because it only goes one line at a time, but it is functional and I haven't got the time to delve into the arcana of emacs configurations. More useful than the wheel is the ability to set the cursor with the mouse, which I assume is thanks to `(xterm-mouse-mode 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit 2:** Just tried running `emacs -Q -nw` in xterm. In this situation `M-x xterm-mouse-mode` makes it possible for me to scroll large buffers with the mouse wheel. So it is possible after all. Can't say why it doesn't work for you without further info.

**Original answer:**
As I understand it, emacs run in a terminal can only get very limited use of the mouse, and only with some terminal emulators. `xterm-mouse-mode` might help, but even then I don't think you can get wheel scrolling, just clicks.

Edit: since you're ssh-ing in, you could try using a GUI version of emacs, either on the remote machine, after connecting via `ssh -x`, or by running emacs locally and using tramp to do the ssh connection. You get all the mouse features this way, shouldn't need any custom tweaking.

Comment: Or run Emacs locally and use Tramp to access remote files.

Answer (score 0):

With Emacs 26.2 and 26.3 running on macOS Mojave I have been able to activate scrolling with the mouse in the using the following Elisp code:

```
(unless (display-graphic-p)
  ;; activate mouse-based scrolling                                                                                                                                     
  (global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-4>") 'pel-scroll-down)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-5>") 'pel-scroll-up))
```

where `pel-scroll-up` and `pel-scroll-down` are commands that call the scroll-up and scroll-down interactive functions with an explicit argument value of 1.

This works as long as the xterm-mouse-mode is active.
I also normally map a key to xterm-mouse-mode to be able to quickly turn it on and off.